# Git - Removing multiple previous commits from both local and remote repo

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

This has more than likely been asked before but I've gotten myself so confused trying to find the solution that I thought it better to just post the specific problem I'm trying to resolve.

I want to completely remove the commits crossed out (see screen grab) leaving the others untouched. As you can see, these commits don't always follow each other. I have already pushed all these commits to remote so I'd need this to reflect there also. Is it possible to do this?

I'm relatively new to using Git so any advice would be great. Thanks.

[Local repo commits - SourceTree screen grab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pl0tW.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already pushed those commits, you shouldn't delete them from history. Doing so will cause other people problems when they pull your changes.

Instead, you can use the [revert](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) command to create a new commit and removes the changes from an earlier commit. When you push this commit to the remote repository, it will have the same effect as deleting the commit, but it won't cause problems when other people pull from that repository.

To remove the most recent commit that is crossed out in your image, enter the following command:

```
git revert 1e3e620
```

Repeat this for any other commits you want to revert, and then push all of those commits to the remote repository.

Comment: No one has pulled from remote yet so would using rebase for now be a better option?

Comment: Doing a rebase would result in a cleaner history - you wouldn't see the original commits nor the revert commit. When pushing to the remote repository after rebasing you will need to include the `--force` parameter though.

Comment: Considering no one else has pulled from the repo then I'll go with rebasing for now. But will keep in mind your solution. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `git rebase -i` to delete the commits, then push to remote with `--force`. (And deal with the upset coworkers who already pulled from the remote...)

Comment: I know for a fact that no one has pulled from remote yet. So would this method be the best route to take?